# I can't get all the string with setAttribute and space

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem with session.setAttribute().
I want to try to get two differents words with setAttribute, for example surnames in a class and I want to get it in a JSP

```
session.setAttribute("Surnames", surnames);
```

but I can get only the first one surname everything after the space it's invisible

```
session.getAttribute("Surnames");
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Share more code.

Comment: if(rs.next()) {
HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();

dbsurnames=rs.getString("Surnames");
sesion.setAttribute("Surnames", dbsurnames);

Comment: Post more code, what does the db schema look like, what's an example row

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list and add your surnames in list and then set this list into session like following:

```
HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
List<String> dbsurnames = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()) { 
    dbsurnames.add(rs.getString("Surnames")); 
}
sesion.setAttribute("Surnames", dbsurnames);
```

Comment: The result of this is []

Comment: Your resultset is not pulling data from database it seems.